# ASM x86 zero terminator

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

There are some problems with printing. It works fine if I use dollar terminated strings. But now I want to print char by char until zero terminator is found. Unfortunately, I get an infinite loop that simply prints first character and nothing else.

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
      input     db 40 dup (?) 
      filename  db 40 dup(?)    

.code   

main:                                                      
      mov ax,seg input
      mov ds,ax

      mov dx,offset input
      mov di, dx 

      mov bx, 82h
      mov cl,[es:80h]  

      mov al,[es:bx]
      cmp al, '-'       
      je increme                

worde:   
      mov al,[es:bx]

      mov [ds:di],al
      inc bx
      inc di

      cmp al,0Dh   ;enter?
      je endprogram

      cmp al, '-'
      jne worde ; if not equal, read next char

      dec di ;overwrite '-' 
    ;-----------------------------------------------------------------;
    ;------------------PRINT IT---------------------------------------;
    ;-----------------------------------------------------------------;
      mov al, 0  ;line terminate
      mov [ds:di], al

print:
      lea bx, input
      mov dl, [bx]

      cmp dl, 0
      je endproc

      mov ah, 02h
      int 21h 

      inc bx
      jmp print

endproc:    
      call new_line
next:
      mov dx,offset filename
      mov di, dx 

worde2:   
      mov al,[es:bx]

      cmp al, '-'       
      je increme         

      mov [ds:di],al
      inc bx
      inc di

      cmp al,0Dh   ;enter?
      je endprogram

      cmp al,20h   ;space? 
      jne worde2
    ;-----------------------------------------------------------------;
    ;------------------PRINT IT---------------------------------------;
    ;-----------------------------------------------------------------;
      mov al, 0  ;line terminate
      mov [ds:di], al
print2:
      lea bx, filename
      mov dl, [bx]

      cmp dl, 0
      je endproc2

      mov ah, 02h
      int 21h 

      inc bx
      jmp print2

endproc2:    
      call new_line
      jmp endprogram

increme:
      inc bx
      jmp worde
increme_next:
      inc bx
      jmp next

endprogram:
      mov ah,4ch   ;end program
      int 21h

new_line:
   push ax
   push bp
   mov ax,0e0ah 
   int 10h
   mov al,13     ;carriage return
   int 10h 
   pop bp
   pop ax
ret

end main
```

**Edit**: After few edits, still get some strange characters:
[image: weird chars]

**Fix:**
Just needed to save `bx` register for later use with `push` and `pop` instructions. That's it

Comment: At the top of your `print` loop, you have `lea bx, input` which keeps going back to the beginning of the line. So your subsequent `inc bx` has no effect. Try moving the `lea bx, input` to *before* the `print:` label. You have the exact same problem in your `print2` loop.

Comment: Can you reduce this to a more minimal example?  Or maybe include comments that describe *why* the code is doing what it's doing.  `cmp al, '-'       ;compare with '-'` is a totally useless comment.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind and will surely include some comments.

Comment: Why are you editing your code with fixes? Imagine if you edit it and fix everything, then what good is the question? And what good would any of the answers be?

Comment: Since you are using _TASM_ have you considered using Turbo Debugger (TD) to step through your code and see where things go wrong?

Comment: I agree with @MichaelPetch. You should be using your debugger. At the very least, you should learn to read and think through your code, as that would uncover a couple of trivial issues.

Comment: I usally use emu8086 for debugging, but it seems like it doesn't understand some of the syntax this time. Anyway, I fixed the rest myself, still thanks for all the comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I often use this function to print a string. I prefer to use int 10h, since it's available immediately after POST and can be used in a real-mode environment whether DOS is loaded or not. (i.e, a boot loader)

```
;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;void PrintString(char *str)
; assumes that DS already holds the seg that contains the string - we're only passing a near pointer
PrintString:
    push    bp
    mov     bp, sp

    push    ax
    push    si

    mov     si, [bp+4]      ; si = str
.getChar:
    lodsb                   ; load a char
    test    al, al          ; is it zero
    jz      .done           ; if so, we're done.
    mov     ah, 0x0e
    int     0x10            ; print the char
    jmp     .getChar        ; and go back for the next one
.done:

    pop     si
    pop     ax

    pop     bp
    ret     2               ; return and remove the argument (*str) from stack.
```

Using it is as simple as:

```
[section .text]
...
push  word .someString
call  PrintString
...
[section .data]
.someString  db 'Hello World!', 10, 13, 0
```

I've used NASM syntax - you'll need to add in the required keywords where appropriate, e.g ADDR